SQLAlchemy implementation overflows Azure SQL Database
Situation: we develop an ETL system that writes a lot of data to Azure SQL Database (as many more around here I guess). For this, we use SQLAlchemy, but are now at the point that we get login timeouts on the Azure DB because we probably overflow the SQL Database login system. It is happening both with sql server authentication and Azure service principal, but we have pinpointed it to be quite surely related to just the sheer number of logins in total and not the login specifically. That's why I ask the following question.
Option 1
This opens a new engine for every writing batch, and thus might be the reason of our inefficiency? (Fyi we also use if_exists="replace", dtype, index=False and chunksize=10000 but I omitted them for shorter code examples
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

for batch in many_batches:
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://user:pw@host/db?driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server")
    connection = engine.connect()
    df.to_sql(table_name, con=connection)
    connection.close()

Option 2
If I understand the documentation well, this option should do the same as option 1? And per the documentation, it is preferred.

We can declare our “connect” block to be a transaction block up front. To do this, we use the Engine.begin() method to get the connection, rather than the Engine.connect() method. This method will manage the scope of the Connection and also enclose everything inside of a transaction with either a COMMIT at the end if the block was successful, or a ROLLBACK if an exception was raised. This style is known as begin once. You should mostly prefer the “begin once” style because it’s shorter and shows the intention of the entire block up front. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

for batch in many_batches:
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://user:pw@host/db?driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server")
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=connection)

Option 3
Now about this third option, the documentation states that:

The start of any SQLAlchemy application is an object called the Engine. This object acts as a central source of connections to a particular database, providing both a factory as well as a holding space called a connection pool for these database connections. The engine is typically a global object created just once for a particular database server, and is configured using a URL string which will describe how it should connect to the database host or backend. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html#tutorial-engine

and

The Engine, when first returned by create_engine(), has not actually tried to connect to the database yet; that happens only the first time it is asked to perform a task against the database. This is a software design pattern known as lazy initialization. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html#tutorial-engine

Which means that the next code will only login once, specifically the first time the df.to_sql() is called, and then executes the write with implicit commit, finally giving the connection back to the connection pool.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://user:pw@host/db?driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server")
for batch in many_batches:
    with engine.begin():
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=connection)

Question
It seems that we should migrate to option 3, but I wonder what the Engine object does when the SQL server is restarted and/or down for some seconds and then comes up again. Let's assume this timeline:









10:24 write started



10:28 write done



10:28 read from REST API started
10:29 server down


10:30 REST API json processing started
10:31 server back alive


10:32 df ready to write



10:32 write started




Option 1 and 2 would've never noticed the server downtime as they create a new engine at 10:32. Is option 3, with a global Engine object, handling these type of problems well? And if so, how?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects

@GordThompson that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

(Answer via link posted by @GordThompson)

The connection pool has the ability to refresh individual connections as well as its entire set of connections, setting the previously pooled connections as “invalid”. A common use case is allow the connection pool to gracefully recover when the database server has been restarted, and all previously established connections are no longer functional. There are two approaches to this.

Disconnect Handling - Pessimistic
Disconnect Handling - Optimistic

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects

Easiest is to set pre_pool_ping to True (pessimistic approach)

If the database is still not available when “pre ping” runs, then the initial connect will fail and the error for failure to connect will be propagated normally. In the uncommon situation that the database is available for connections, but is not able to respond to a “ping”, the “pre_ping” will try up to three times before giving up, propagating the database error last received.

Futhermore:

It is critical to note that the pre-ping approach does not accommodate for connections dropped in the middle of transactions or other SQL operations. If the database becomes unavailable while a transaction is in progress, the transaction will be lost and the database error will be raised.

The last quote is simply SQL, a transaction that runs during server issues should always fail imho. That is a feature that SQLAlchemy shouldn't (and luckily didn't) fix.
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute("select username from users")
    for row in result:
        print("username:", row['username'])


Above, the Engine.connect() method returns a Connection object, and by using it in a Python context manager (e.g. the with: statement) the Connection.close() method is automatically invoked at the end of the block. The Connection, is a proxy object for an actual DBAPI connection. The DBAPI connection is retrieved from the connection pool at the point at which Connection is created. When the Connection is closed at the end of the with: block, the referenced DBAPI connection is released to the connection pool. From the perspective of the database itself, the connection pool will not actually “close” the connection assuming the pool has room to store this connection for the next use.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#basic-usage

So, keeping an active connection from a database / SQL Server perspective is implemented by keeping the Engine alive in SQLAlchemy, not the Connection.
